# How can I add text to a php string that generates dynamically a Page Title?

Tags: php

I am currently using this script:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->setTitle($event->title)
```

and I need to do something like this:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->setTitle($event->title + | text)
```

So I want to dynamically generate a Page title "`$event->title`" and add "`| text`" to it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP concatenation operator is `.`

```
JFactory::getDocument()->setTitle($event->title . "| text")
```